# How to show that the number of positive common divisor of $n$ is $ \Pi_{1}^{r} (a_{i} +1) $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_r^{a_r}$

I am unsure of how to proceed with this problem any hints/suggestions welcome

Comment: Use the result of your previous question.

Comment: Between this and [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480189/how-to-prove-d0-is-a-divisor-of-n-iff-d-p-1b-1p-2b-2-p-rb-r-wi) it looks like you are just posting your homework here for us to do for you.  What have you tried?  Can you do it for, say, a prime power?

Comment: I really don't know how to use the previous result on this question

Answer (score 0):

A prime $p$ has $2$ divisors, $1,p$

$p^2$ has $3$ divisors, $1,p,p^2$

$p^n$ has $n+1$ divisors, $1,p,p^2,\ldots,p^n$

If $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime then $ab$ has the product of the number of divisors of $a$ by the number of divisors of $b$

In a factorization  factors are prime, then relatively prime

$n=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\ldots p_r^{a_r}$

the number of factors of $n$ is then the following

$$(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\ldots(a_r+1)=\prod_{i=1}^{r} (a_{i} +1)$$

Hope this helps

Comment: Helped a lot many thanks!